# NSHTTPURLRequest header

Tags: iphone, http-status-codes

I would like to get some information from a website. I have already got the HTML code of the website. However, I would like to get more header information of the website (e.g. http status code)

After read the apple library, I found that there are 2 methods which can display those information. However, I can only use one of the methods (has warning), another cannot be used.

The following is the code.

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *responseAlllHeaderFields = [response allHeaderFields];
// how can I convent the NSDictionary to the NSString, I cannot use the NSLog to display the information
NSLog(responseAlllHeaderFields); // <-- wrong

// returns the HTTP status code for the response
NSInteger *responseStatusCode = [response statusCode];
// warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
NSLog(@"\nThe status code is %d\n", responseStatusCode);
```

Besides, are there are any other methods to get the header informatino?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can do `NSLog(@"The header fields are %@", responseAllHeaderFields);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your reply.

However, there are some warning.

The following is the code

```
NSInteger *responseStatusCode = [[response statusCode] intValue];
NSLog(@"\nThe status code is %d\n", responseStatusCode);

NSInteger *responseStatusCode = [response statusCode];
[responseStatusCode intValue];
NSLog(@"\nThe status code is %d\n", responseStatusCode);

NSInteger *responseStatusCode = [response statusCode];
NSLog(@"\nThe status code is %d\n", [responseStatusCode intValue]);
```

I have no ideas why the above 3 methods are wrong and cannot be work.

Thank you.

Comment: You are still making `responseStatusCode` an `NSInteger *`. Drop the pointer cast `*`, it's the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the warning because NSInteger is a wrapper for `int`. So you don't need the pointer `*`. Change the left side of the assignment to just `NSInteger responseStatusCode` and see if the warning goes away.